# EJB batch process

Tags: batch-processing, ejb-3.1, hibernate-search

I have been working on my project using EJB 3.1 running on a JBoss EAP (http://www.jboss.org/products/eap). I am using Hibernate Search as my persistence. What I am looking for is a way of calling the manual indexing in my EJBs and not getting transaction timeout as a result.

10:55:28,557 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Hibernate Search: collectionsloader-6) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
10:55:28,557 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Hibernate Search: collectionsloader-6) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction

I have been searching some examples and I don't want to force every transaction in my jboss to be more than the usual time.

[Why Hibernate Search takes so much time to build a Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295800/why-hibernate-search-takes-so-much-time-to-build-a-index)

On the other hand I have been thinking about calling a batch process from my EJB but I am not really sure about how to do it. Moreover, I didn't find anything interesting on the Web....

Any ideas on how to call the mass indexer in order to regenerate my indexes?

fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

Or, in general, anybody can tell the best way of calling a batch process from a EJB?

Thanks in advance,

Hibernator,

Comment: I found this link http://bodez.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/custom-indexing-using-java-threads-with-hibernate-search/

Comment: So what is your final solution then? If you still have problems, could you post the full stack trace? With EE 6, you could maybe use a timer?

Comment: For the moment I don't have any solution using fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

I have web services in order to index one entity each time. I would like to improve my indexing time using createIndexer but the transaction expires.

Do you have any example using Timer?

I use Stateless EJB 3.1 running on a JBoss EAP server, but I can change to any other J2EE solution. I just need an example...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this link...maybe could be the solution to my problem...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281288/delete-huge-number-of-rows-from-an-ejb-timer